# Convert a float in scientific notation to a "d.dd x 10^(-n)"

Tags: python

I'm building a calculator to calculate some chemistry related calculations. So most of the results will be extremely small values.

An example result is `4.840909814726882e-09`.

How do I display this value in a format like `4.84 x 10^(-9)`?

Comment: `format(num, '.2e')` will generate `4.84e-09`, which isn't exacly what you want but it's getting closer.

Comment: `f'{str(a)[:4]} x 10^({str(a)[-3:]})'` can work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```py
format(4.840909814726882e-09, '.2e').replace('e', ' x 10^(') + ')'
```

**Output:**
`4.84 x 10^(-09)`
It's not *exactly* the result you wanted but it's simple.

Also there is:

```py
def my_format(num):
    s = format(num, '.2e')
    base, exp = s.split('e')
    return f'{base} x 10^({int(exp)})'
```

**Output:**

```
>>> my_format(4.840909814726882e-09)
'4.84 x 10^(-9)'
```

which is more coplicated but it's exectly the result you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I display the value to a format like 4.84 x 10^(-9) ?

By hand, that is not a format supported by Python.

Although if you just want to "round off" the number because you neither have nor need 15 significant digits, then you can use [format specifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), and either the `g` presentation type:

```
>>> format(v, 'g')
'4.84091e-09'
```

or an explicit precision:

```
>>> format(v, '.3')
'4.84e-09'
```

Comment: That is rather explicitly noted  in the answer?

Comment: OP uses the wording "a format like x", it is not made clear whether they want this exact formatting, or just want to avoid the completely unnecessary precision of the default formatting. I assumed the latter could or would be of use given Python can easily generate it natively.

Comment: I have tried your method before , but i want to format it to 4.84 x 10^(-9)